# Apache Virtual Host showing its works but not loading the correct index

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion, virtualhost

I am using this configuration and my .dev is working fine but its displaying `it works` instead of whats in the `index.php` is there a default `index.php`?

MACOSX

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/Jess/Sites/dev/%1/"
    ServerName vhosts.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    ErrorLog "/Users/Jess/Sites/dev/vhosts-error_log"

    <Directory "/Users/Jess/Sites/dev/*">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: I don't think it is reading this config. `it works` is from the default `index.php` file. That file is usually in your `/var/www/html` folder, or could be `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs`. Are you XAMPP or the default apache server that comes with OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the default file is `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html`. Make sure your configuration file is added at the end of `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Something like this:

```
Include /etc/apache2/users/XXXXX.conf
```